# Is it a good pattern to use array map instead of FlatList in React Native?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am currently developing an App with comments section to article. Is it a good idea to write the screen with comments using `ScrollView` and `map()` through all elements in comments array? Something like:

```
<ScrollView>
  {
    comments.map(comment => (
      <View>{/* comment related content */}</View>
    ))
  }
</ScrollView>
```

The main reason why I don't want to use `FlatList` is scrolling ability to the specific comment, knowing that `View` with comment is going to have variable height (without `FlatList` I expect the `ScrollView` to allow me to scroll to the position returned by `onLayout`). The second thing is that `FlatList` doesn't render all items at once, so I will not be able to scroll to comment which is far down the list. The scroll mechanism will stuck at the last rendered element which is not what I want to achieve. Therefore I want to ditch `FlatList` completely. Will I have considerable performance problem if my list be like 50-60 of items? I don't expect the users to write more comments to the article.

Answer (score 0):

`Absolutely not`, `FlatList` is much more optimized and have more power than `ScrollView`

Anything that is possible with ScrollView can be done with FlatList but there are cases that are not supported by ScrollView like `onEndReched`, `initialNumToRender`, `viewabilityConfig` and much more also all of the props of ScrollView is supported by `FlatList` too.

Also, you can render any number of the items with `FlatList` at once.

Performance issues depend on what you are doing inside the items of the list but if 50 or 60 items in a list with some simpple view, there will be no issues even with `ScrollView`

Read more about FlatList.
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#docsNav

Comment: Thank you for your response. It seems that FlatList has more options than I thought. I will try to play with it.

Comment: Yeah, No doubt about that `FlatList` having more options than `ScrollView`